# display required sub-sites links in web part in a site of SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part

I want to show some of the sub sites in a web part of main site. I have 10 sub sites of which 4 of them are work-space sites. I want to show all the work-space sites on the main site in a web part. I tried to use table of contents but it shows all the sub sites belonging to the site. I want only my required sites to be shown in web part as links . Can some one suggest on how to approach this in SharePoint 2010. thanks in advance.

Comment: What identifies the required sites? If there is nothing special or "automatic" here you could just use Summary links webpart and add the links manually

Comment: @robert lindgren whenever we create a workspace site the link should be populated at the web part which cannot be done through summary links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following code snippet and use it in a custom webpart/visual web part to filter and display the links of the specific template based sub sites.

```
    using Microsoft.SharePoint;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Meetings;


            public void DisplayLinks()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sitecollectionrul"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("subsitename"))
                    {
                        //// IsMeetingWorkspaceWeb Method is used to determine whether the specified Web site was created by using a Meeting Workspace template
                        if (SPMeeting.IsMeetingWorkspaceWeb(web))
                        {
add your logic to display the links here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot use server side coding in our environment. Thnaks for the snippet though .